# how get and element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to choose a element using the Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"] but I feeling a little lost when I try to find a check box by his name and value.

this is a example of the checkbox

```
<input id="check-box-nat-Español" name="kid[native_languages][]" type="checkbox" value="50f97f5304fec25b00000001">
```

I have a lot of checkbox with the same name, so I need to find the checkbox using the name and the value.

I'm trying this, but it did not work.

```
$("input[name="kid[native_languages][]"][value=50f97f5304fec25b00000001]").attr("checked",true);​
```

Any help please!

Comment: You have to use only one attribute at once thats it
$("input[value=50f97f5304fec25b00000001]").prop("checked",true);​

Comment: Did you mean that you have many checkboxes with same id?

Comment: @Jain You can use multiple attribute selectors...

Comment: Jain, I can't do that, beacuse I have two tipe of checkbox a group for native language and a group for practise language, so I have two checkbox whith the same value but whit different name

Comment: Sorry Garath, I wrote name

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I know this but here we can required first one because it is an name array

Comment: @Jean Okay that fine!!

Comment: ANthonyGrist, How can I do that?

Comment: @Jean, please correct your question wordings first otherwise it may not useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error while selecting. You should use:

```
$("input[name='kid[native_languages][]'][value='50f97f5304fec25b00000001']").attr("checked",true)
```

**[Link To Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S78ma/)**

Answer (score 2):

use single quotes and it should work

```
$("input[name='kid[native_languages][]'][value=50f97f5304fec25b00000001]").attr("checked",true);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DwBP2/)

Comment: checked is not a attribute it is a property

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes around your selector so that they wont interfere with the ones inside

```
$('input[name="kid[native_languages][]"][value=50f97f5304fec25b00000001]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='kid[native_languages][]'][value=50f97f5304fec25b00000001]").prop("checked",true);​
```